# Connection timeout value in Odata Configuration

Tags: 2011, odata

Is there any configuration to tell Odata to timeout if the Broker Db takes more time to respond ?

In other terms is there any query(SQL connection) timeout settings in Odata ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the IdleTimeOut Settings in the cd_storage.xml to adjust number of seconds that a connection can be idle before it is being closed. It is set to 120 seconds by default.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that most of the underlying mechanisms under the Content Delivery Web Service are the same that Standard Content Delivery uses, particularly the storage configuration - in other words, this is the same setting for Tridion CD - with or without OData

Comment: That is the only timeout settings i could see in the storage config but my need is to timeout when a query(Odata Call) runs for a long time due to any reason(network slowness, huge data , etc,.). Is there a way to mention that in Odata configuration other than doing it in application ?